# JQuery change variable value outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value of my "clients" variable from outside the function, with the one from inside the function(which changes when I select something), and I dont know how to do that. Please help

This is my code code

```
<script>
    var clients;
    $('#clients').on('change',function(e)
    {
        console.log(e);

        var clients = e.target.value;

    });
    document.write(clients);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`var` keyword creates a local variable. Remove it to have access to variable from the outer scope:

```
var clients;
$('#clients').on('change', function(e) {
    clients = e.target.value;
});
```

However, you should keep in mind that `alert(clients)` in your last line will always display `undefined` as the `change` event will be triggered later when the actual event will fire.

Comment: Bah, beat you to the answer by 39 seconds but you get extra votes. Its that "mindreading the OP's next question" bit at the end that got you the extra's isnt it?! ;)

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesent work :( !. Clients still remains undefined. I changed alert() with document.write(). :(

Comment: @Nova_virus: Of course it's `undefined`. You don't assign a value to it until the `change` event is executed. Also, don't use `document.write`.

Comment: @Jamiec It appears so `:)` Besides my side note didn't really help.

Comment: @MattBurland -> thanks for the explanation. I am new to jQuery/javascript, and your answer really helped explaining the basics of events. Sorry for thanking you so late :). Also, can you explain to me why I should not use document.write ?

Comment: @Nova_virus: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) for some discussion of `document.write`. The short version is, if you are not careful, a call to `document.write` can end up completely clearing the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

by using `var` inside the function you're redefining it in that scope, just remove `var` inside the function

```
var clients;
$('#clients').on('change',function(e)
{
    console.log(e);

    clients = e.target.value;

});
alert(clients);
```

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesent work :( !. Clients still remains undefined. I changed alert() with document.write(). :(

Comment: @Nova_virus it appears you're not understanding how event handlers work. See The note underneath the other answer.